# Creating different layouts for different screens in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, resize

I'm having a lot of trouble setting up a propery layout for different devices. For devices which go under the same densities, objects are appearing differently, and I just don't know how to differentiate between the devices. Our smart friends at Google decided that it was a good idea to put "xxhdpi" for some devices, and then a number for other devices. Regardless, the devices still display objects differently.

Nexus 6P: https://i.stack.imgur.com/761aL.png (560 dpi)

Nexus 5: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbYhI.png (xxhdpi)

See how the hand scrolling is on the white box on one of them, while the other one has it off the box.

Now, if I create a layout-sw560dp, then it says that the layout is only for tablets since it only allows me to preview the layout on only tablets. If I try layout-large, then it does the exact same thing, saying that only applies to tablets. So I have read over the Supporting Multiple Layouts documentation, and it doesn't help.

What layout am I suppose to create to differentiate between Nexus 6P and Nexus 5? What about Nexus 5X?